# Write a script that generates several directories, makes empty files, and then lists all file under the current directory

Tags: python, linux

I'm extremely new to linux and I have very very little experience with it.
The work I want to do:

1. write a script that generates a few directories, then
2. makes at least 5 empty files, and then
3. lists them all under the current directories.

I don't know how to start doing this.

Comment: Please clarify. Your title says "directories" but your post says "dictionaries". What do you want?

Comment: Sorry, it is directories

Answer (score 2):

check [shell script](http://linuxcommand.org/writing_shell_scripts.php) for writing a linux script then use:

- `mkdir [folder name]` : command to create directory
- `touch [file name]` : to create a file
- `ls` : to list file and directories

learning is fun and welcome to linux :D

Comment: So I would use those three commands to create a directory/file/and list them?

Comment: yeah but if you want to automated it (like automatically create 5 files), check the link that i provide, and write a shell script.  :D

Comment: So all the information on how to make it automatically create  files is in that link?

Comment: to be precise, tutorial how to write a shell script for linux, when you have understand that, then automatically create files would be very easy. try it :D

Comment: Which section would it be under? Because I'm struggling to find which bit :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the benefits of Linux itself.

Use a bash script instead of python, and use touch.
Google for both to know what to do.